# Is it possible to install Pods/SDKs on demand/when needed in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdk, cocoapods

Actually in my case I want to install a specific SDK only when it is needed. e.g. If user has a permission of something only then the SDK should get installed otherwise not.

Comment: No, all executable code must be included in the package that you send to Apple for review and which they sign before making it available in the App Store.

Comment: Hi @Paulw, it will great if you share a apple documents which said the same thing.

Comment: I haven't got any references to hand, but it is an obvious implication from the way the App Store works. You need to submit all of your code in a single bundle to Apple for review. Once they have approved it, they sign the bundle and make it available in the App Store. There is no way you could dynamically add code after the bundle is signed.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible because POD dependencies are installed before application is build and you need to run pod install once before building and launching the app

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Libraries need to be compiled before being bundled into the app. So the cocoapods, SPM or Carthage cannot be used as On Demand Resource.

Following types can be used as On demand resources.
Image Courtesy: Apple documentation

[image]